# How does scikit-learn's kNN model handle zero-distances when using inverse distance weighting?

Tags: scikit-learn, k-nearest-neighbour

OK, I could go through the code to figure this out but I feel something Googleable doesn't hurt.

When I'm using a kNN classifier with (inverse) distance weighting, how does it handle cases whereby the distance between the prediction input and (m)any of the k nearest training records is zero? What if some of them aren't?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

KNN classifier in scikit-learn uses [`_get_weights`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/neighbors/_base.py) method in `sklearn.neighbors.base` library. The inverse weighting is achieved when `'distance'` is given as `weights` paremeter. You can also call this function directly by giving your distances as input. The weight is $w=\frac{1}{d}$, but surprisingly, when $d$ is $0$, the weight is always set to $1$. In the code, it does an `np.isinf` check and when a weight is infinite, it is set to the boolean value produced by `np.isinf`.

Comment: Thanks. Mmh. I was hoping that in a mixed case where say first nearest neighbour has distance 0, it would trump any other neighbour with distance >0. Setting it to weight=1 doesn't seem right. What would the "correct" approach be? Simple voting among all neighbours with distance=0 and discarding all other neihbours?

Comment: I'd at least set the weight to a large value, using some epsilon, or maybe discard that sample. But, I wouldn't do weight = 1. I don't know why they choose such a solution.